# Click event on anything except specific DOM-node in a React app

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

what is the best way to catch and handle a click event on "anything except specific DOM-node(s)" in a React app?

Answer (score 0):

The handler of the click event is the easy part: this can be any method.
The registration of the event, and the trigger to invoke the handler, is the hard part.

There is no clean way to capture a "clicks outside ...." event.
There are however various (HTML/ CSS/ Javascript) tricks you could apply:

- If it is a modal page/ popup, you could also render a full page background rectangle (e.g. slightly transparent grey), which is in front of the whole page, but behind the popup. Add a click-event-listener to this background to remove the modal + the grey background.
- Another method is to use the *focusout* javascript event on your top-react component:

  - the top HTML component rendered by react should be able to get focus (needs to be an `<a>` or similar HTML, or - somewhat less clean - needs a `tabindex=...` to work)
  - give the element focus as soon as it is rendered (inside componentDidMount()`)
  - add a focusout event listener, which triggers the handler to do something with the click outside.

The focusout event is fired as soon as the component no longer has focus:
 - if a child of the component gets focus (e.g. you click something inside the component) focusout is also fired: usually no problem for menu's, but undesired for popups with forms
 - the focusout is also fired if the user presses TAB.

Answer (score 0):

There's no React-specific way to do this; all React event handlers are tied to the component they're set on. The *best* way to accomplish this depends on the details of what you need to get done, but a fairly straightforward way to address this would be to add a delegated click handler to the body element, or the closest ancestor element that includes the area you want to capture clicks from. You'd attach this event handler either on the component's componentDidMount() or whenever it becomes relevant, for example, after toggling the component's state so that it shows a dropdown menu.

Attach the event handler however you normally would – element.addEventListener or jQuery's $().on or what-have-you - and evaluate the event target when it fires to determine whether you need to execute your custom logic.

Simple example, without jQuery:

```
componentDidMount() {
   document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target !== [your dom node]) {
     // do something
    }
   }
 }
```

Attaching a single event handler on the body element shouldn't pose any performance issues, but best practice for most cases where you'd use something like this would be to remove the event handler when it's no longer needed.